# Is there a way I can build a virtual environment with the same versions of libraries from outside the VE?

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-venv

If I have an environment with python and pandas and other libraries installed (this can be a docker container, or the host machine itself or perhaps a conda environment) and I want to have a virtual environment (with venv?) *with the same version of the libraries* , how can I create that virtual environment?

(Why would you need that)<- you can say.

Well I want to have a virtual environment with the same versions as the host and then install some other libraries inside that I don't want to install in the host.

But other than that, the libraries versions have to be *the same*

Comment: This is a very common task. E.g., `conda create -n new_env --clone old_env` is the idiomatic way to do this with Conda (though don't do this with **base**).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of installed libraries and then install from the list.

```bash
# Step 1: Create requirements.txt
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt

# Step 2: Create virtual environment
python -m venv venv

# Step 3: Activate virtual environment
. venv/bin/activate

# Step 4: Install packages inside virtual environment 
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

in your first venv. It will create a file with all the libraries you have and their versions. And then

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in your second one.